# Sobipro component respond with a blank page

Tags: component, joomla-3.7

I update Joomla to the most recent version (3.7.1).

Also update the Joomla component SobriPro to the most recent version (1.3.7).

Before the updates all works fine, after the updates the SobriPro component always responds with an empty page. Accessing SobiPro client or administration pages always retune a blank html page.

I already consult the administration and client Joomla error logs but nothing is register. I also try to run Joomla in debug mode but not getting any message.

Sure I run the updates first in a local dev environment. In the local server all runs OK, I only have problems in the production environment.

Comment: Maybe the SobiPro update didn't go well on the live server. Try re-installing sobipro. What happens if you upload the working version from your local dev?

Comment: @FFrewin how can I reinstall SobiPro component without losing all my data?

Comment: I update my production version in my local server and all works fine. So, it must be some server configuration that I am missing.

Comment: Check your links and urls if contains caraters like this "&amp;" i have the solution for you

Comment: Turn Error Reporting in System tab of your Global Configuration to "Development". Alternatively you can try to look into server logs (not cms logs, those do not include php errors). This coupled with System Debug should give a glimpse into what causes the error.

Comment: @ArturStępień I change the Error Reporting to Develoment as you said but I keep receiving only a blank page. I use CPanel to manage the server. Throughout the log error that the CPanel interface provide I can't see any error related with the sobiPro component.

Comment: @G.Mansour what are the links and urls that you talking about? Are you talking about the links and urls inside the content of the sobiPro component?

Comment: It doesn't have to be related to sobiPro. Sometimes some plugins can just have conflicts with the component. Did you tried to contact sobiPro suppoer? If there are any conflicts in 3.7.1 they should know about it. As a temporary solution you can try to downgrade.

Comment: Sorry my ignorance @ArturStępień but can you tell me how is the better way to downgrade in order not to lose my data.

Comment: @miguelbgouveia , no it's not related to sobiPro it's a joomla update issue that will be be fixed in the next update 3.7.2 , link in your menu when your navigate look like domaine.com/index.php?itemId=123&amp;view=edit shoud not show `&amp;`

Comment: @G.Mansour I think that is not the case for me. My link to the component is in this form: [mydomain]/administrator/index.php?option=com_sobipro

Comment: @miguelbgouveia If the component don't work as it should or don't work at all after update its most likely caused by incompatibility with new version of Joomla. if you can't contact sobiPro support to get some info about possible issues in Joomla! 3.7.1 and you need the component to work downgrade is the only possible solution if you don't have high PHP skills to debug it your self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. 
In my production environment dosen’t have the Phar extension available.

The difficult to detect this limitation was because the sobi component return black pages without reporting any error.

To correct the problem I just uncompressed the sobi framework file and make a change in the sobi component loader code. This change is documented here: https://github.com/Sigsiu-NET/SobiPro/pull/8